# Oracle 19c Trigger INSTEAD OF on View; CHAR and VARCHAR2 fields wont bind PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.component'

Tags: sql, oracle, bind, collation, database-trigger

I'm trying to work over views to insert into different tables depending on the contents to be inserted; in the following example it's using date to insert into different tables using an instead of trigger.

The problem I have is that it just will not bind. I've tried using dynamic sql in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements to try to work around but the columns that are character based will not bind. My wonder is whether it's my table and view collation that's causing the issue? But it could be a major EBCAK any advice much appreciated.

### ** UPDATE NON-CASE NEW SCHEMA, NON-QUOTED **

```
DROP VIEW TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded;
DROP TABLE TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded23SEP19;
DROP TABLE TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded24SEP19;
DROP TABLE TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded25SEP19;
/

CREATE TABLE TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded23SEP19  (txn CHAR(36 BYTE) COLLATE BINARY_CI, 
    stack_trace CLOB COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP,  originating_file NVARCHAR2(500) COLLATE BINARY_CI, originating_line_nr NUMBER(20,0), 
    date_and_time TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_events_recorded23SEP19 PRIMARY KEY (txn));

CREATE TABLE TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded24SEP19  (txn CHAR(36 BYTE) COLLATE BINARY_CI, 
    stack_trace CLOB COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP,  originating_file NVARCHAR2(500) COLLATE BINARY_CI, originating_line_nr NUMBER(20,0), 
    date_and_time TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_events_recorded24SEP19 PRIMARY KEY (txn));

CREATE TABLE TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded25SEP19  (txn CHAR(36 BYTE) COLLATE BINARY_CI, 
    stack_trace CLOB COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP,  originating_file NVARCHAR2(500) COLLATE BINARY_CI, originating_line_nr NUMBER(20,0), 
    date_and_time TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_events_recorded25SEP19 PRIMARY KEY (txn));

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE NONEDITIONABLE VIEW TEST_ORACLE.events_recorded ( txn, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr, date_and_time) DEFAULT COLLATION BINARY_CI  AS 
SELECT txn, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr, date_and_time FROM events_recorded23SEP19 UNION ALL SELECT txn, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr, date_and_time FROM events_recorded24SEP19 UNION ALL SELECT txn, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr, date_and_time FROM events_recorded25SEP19;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER events_recorded_trigger DEFAULT COLLATION BINARY_CI 
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON events_recorded FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '') = '23SEP19' THEN
    INSERT INTO events_recorded23SEP19 (txn, date_and_time, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr) VALUES (:NEW.txn, :NEW.date_and_time, :NEW.stack_trace, :NEW.originating_file, :NEW.originating_line_nr);
  ELSIF INSERTING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '') = '24SEP19' THEN
    INSERT INTO events_recorded24SEP19 (txn, date_and_time, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr) VALUES (:NEW.txn, :NEW.date_and_time, :NEW.stack_trace, :NEW.originating_file, :NEW.originating_line_nr);
  ELSIF INSERTING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '') = '25SEP19' THEN
    INSERT INTO events_recorded25SEP19 (txn, date_and_time, stack_trace, originating_file, originating_line_nr) VALUES (:NEW.txn, :NEW.date_and_time, :NEW.stack_trace, :NEW.originating_file, :NEW.originating_line_nr);
  ELSIF UPDATING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '')  = '23SEP19' THEN
    UPDATE events_recorded23SEP19 SET txn = :NEW.txn, date_and_time = :NEW.date_and_time, stack_trace = :NEW.stack_trace, originating_file = :NEW.originating_file, originating_line_nr = :NEW.originating_line_nr WHERE txn = :OLD.txn;
  ELSIF UPDATING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '')  = '24SEP19' THEN
    UPDATE events_recorded24SEP19 SET txn = :NEW.txn, date_and_time = :NEW.date_and_time, stack_trace = :NEW.stack_trace, originating_file = :NEW.originating_file, originating_line_nr = :NEW.originating_line_nr WHERE txn = :OLD.txn;
  ELSIF UPDATING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '')  = '25SEP19' THEN
    UPDATE events_recorded25SEP19 SET txn = :NEW.txn, date_and_time = :NEW.date_and_time, stack_trace = :NEW.stack_trace, originating_file = :NEW.originating_file, originating_line_nr = :NEW.originating_line_nr WHERE txn = :OLD.txn;
  ELSIF DELETING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '')  = '23SEP19' THEN
    DELETE FROM events_recorded23SEP19 WHERE txn = :OLD.txn;
  ELSIF DELETING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '')  = '24SEP19' THEN
    DELETE FROM events_recorded24SEP19 WHERE txn = :OLD.txn;
  ELSIF DELETING AND replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '')  = '25SEP19' THEN
    DELETE FROM events_recorded25SEP19 WHERE txn = :OLD.txn;
  END IF; 
END;
```

So the above still gives the error:

```
Trigger EVENTS_RECORDED_TRIGGER compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/121     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
3/169     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
5/121     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
5/169     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
7/121     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
7/169     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
9/45      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
9/142     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
9/224     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TXN'
11/45     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
11/142    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
11/224    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TXN'
13/45     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
13/142    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
13/224    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TXN'
15/52     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TXN'
17/52     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TXN'
19/52     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TXN'
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: get rid of double quotes

Comment: Unrelated, but it is a very bad idea to create your objects in the SYSTEM schema.  You should create a named user to hold your application objects and forget that SYSTEM even exists.  Oracle recommends that you not even log into SYSTEM to perform database administration: _While this account can be used to perform day-to-day administrative tasks, Oracle strongly recommends creating named users account for administering the Oracle database to enable monitoring of database activity._ (from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/users_secure.htm#ADMQS12004)

Comment: Do you really store hard-coded DATE values in your trigger? Very bad design. And you compare them with strings which are dependent on current user session NLS-Settings - compare with `DATE` values.

Comment: Thanks yep it's on my todo list to get it into a new schema. Double quotes is a pain to remove for me; the client code executes against postgres, microsoft sql server and oracle and particularly it uses id columns called id unfortunately. So in oracle this is a particular pain because i therefore have to quote the column name which implies case sensitivity. Will try without though to see what happens ... :)

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem which ID is. True it's a keyword in Oracle but it's not reserved and it's perfectly permissible to create tables with a column called ID in Oracle. Likewise OWNER and COMPONENT.

Comment: I have tried to run your script. It failed for me on ORA-43929, because you have all that Collation syntax and my local database has `MAX_STRING_SIZE=STANDARD`. I'm afraid I draw the line at re-making a database to answer an SO question. I removed all the COLLATE and COLLATION instructions and your posted script compiles in its entirety.

Comment: i'll see if i can deploy a standard install of oracle and debug that first ...

Comment: ok i see when you run in standard mode you cannot have collation; the exact error is ```ERROR at line 1:
ORA-43929: Collation cannot be specified if parameter MAX_STRING_SIZE=STANDARD
is set.``` sadly since it seems that collation is needed to demonstrate the issue i'll need to rely on somebody else. Many thanks @APC for your time on this though, wierd issue!

Comment: Perhaps you could look into using a partitioned table instead of a bunch of tables with the date in their name and a rather complex trigger to distribute actions amongst those tables.

Comment: *"i'll need to rely on somebody else"* - have you see @MatthewMcPeak's comment on my answer? `DEFAULT COLLATION BINARY_CI` is not legal syntax. Try fixing that and see what happens.

Comment: Oh sorry the default collation was not at fault, sorry this trigger has been through about 100 permutations trying to find a successful syntax, it started out without it and i've tried since without as well :( many thanks though to you both. As Bob shows below this is actually driven from some dynamic sql originally but i've reduced to try to show the problem the easiest way.

Comment: Sorry one more reason why it's done with triggers, i have a few different ways of using this technique one is where i have active and inactive tables so as to allow background processing of large operations to take place; what happens is clear inactive, *slowly* copy active to inactive, perform batch operation during which time triggers are used to apply running actions to both active and inactive tables then finally swap back if batch operation is successful. If batch operation is unsuccessful then revert view and drop inactive.

Comment: Unrelated, but. `replace(to_char(:NEW.date_and_time), '-', '') = '23SEP19'` is better written as `trunc(:new.date_and_time) = date '2019-09-23'`

Answer (score 2):

This is an INSTEAD OF trigger on a view `"events_recorded"`. So the relevant DDL would be the `create or replace view` statement. My guess is the case of the columns defined in the view's projection don't match the double-quoted case of the variables referenced in the trigger.

Of course it may be some other variance but the root cause is the view does not have columns called `"component"`, `"transaction_id"`, `"originating_file"`, `"owner"` or  `"linked_entity"`.

---

I have tried to run your revised script. It failed for me on ORA-43929, because you have all that Collation syntax and my local database has MAX_STRING_SIZE=STANDARD. I'm afraid I draw the line at re-making a database to answer an SO question. I removed all the COLLATE and COLLATION instructions and your posted script compiles in its entirety.

> so somehow it's the collation of these columns (sic) causing the pain

It seems that way, although it's hard to see why it should. If you have an Oracle Support account I suggest you raise a ticket with them.

Comment: Sorry i think i've re-created without the quotes and that i'm still 99% certain my column and tables are correct

Comment: I will try to make a minimal example :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this i've minified the example i hope

Comment: so remving the collation from the columns means that now the trigger works; so somehow it's the collation of these collumns causing the pain

Comment: I am not sure if it's relevant to your problem, but `DEFAULT COLLATION BINARY_CI` is not legal syntax.  The only allowed value for `DEFAULT COLLATION` is `USING_NLS_COMP`.  See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/DEFAULT-COLLATION-clause.html#GUID-453FC0EA-7B83-407B-A991-87A48017B358.  Restriction holds in 19c documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use dynamic SQL to make your life a little nicer here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER events_recorded_trigger
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON EVENTS_RECORDED
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  strStmt  VARCHAR2(32000);
  strDate  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  strDate := TO_CHAR(NVL(:NEW.DATE_AND_TIME, :OLD.DATE_AND_TIME), 'DDMONRR');

  IF INSERTING THEN
    strStmt := 'INSERT INTO events_recorded' || strDate ||
               '(txn, date_and_time, stack_trace, originating_file,originating_line_nr)' ||
               ' VALUES (:a, :b, :c, :d, :e)';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strStmt
     USING :NEW.txn, :NEW.date_and_time, :NEW.stack_trace,
           :NEW.originating_file, :NEW.originating_line_nr;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    strStmt := 'UPDATE events_recorded' || strDate ||
               ' SET txn = :a, date_and_time = :b, stack_trace = :c, ' ||
               '     originating_file = :d, originating_line_nr = :e ' ||
               ' WHERE txn = :f';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strStmt
      USING :NEW.txn, :NEW.date_and_time, :NEW.stack_trace, 
            :NEW.originating_file, :NEW.originating_line_nr, :OLD.txn;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    strStmt := 'DELETE FROM events_recorded' || strDate ||
               ' WHRE txt = :a';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strStmt
      USING :OLD.txn;
  END IF; 
END events_recorded_trigger;
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, yep it looks very similar to that in its natural state but even like that it wouldn't bind :( trying to compile the above shows:```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
12/12     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
13/12     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
21/13     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TXN'
22/13     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ORIGINATING_FILE'
```

Comment: In your actual tables in your database, are the names still case-sensitive/quoted - i.e. `"originating_file"` instead of `ORIGINATING_FILE`? [This dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3668ce17cf33baf5f71f471b3c6cc2d) shows that the code (with a couple minor syntax errors fixed :-) compiles fine. If those identifiers are still case-sensitive you're going to have to quote them every time you use them.

Comment: Hi bob, nope for the time being i've taken all quotes out :)